# Вырезать цифры после текста JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Может кто помочь с регулярками, есть вот такая строка

```
ТЕРРИТОРИАЛЬНЫМ ПУНКТОМ УФМС РОССИИ ПО ПЕНЗЕНСКОЙ ОБЛ ПЕНЗЕНСКОМ РАИОНЕ  10 05 2010  560 040  ЁЭ   ЛЫ 90  ЁЁ  5  ОГ 19    53 4 АГАПОВА ОАН 394 ВЕ 34 
ЕКАТЕРИНА 798 МИХАИЛОВНА 398 1 ЖЕН 12 05 1996 2 
ГОР ПЕНЗА  ПЕНЗЕНСКОГО  НА  ПЕНЗЕНСКОЙ ОБЛ
```

Нужно вырезать с нее все цифры кроме 10 05 2010  560 040 (это первые 14 цифр) и 12 05 1996 это 8 цифр всегда идут сразу после слова ЖЕН/МУЖ
Нужно получить вот такой текст

```
ТЕРРИТОРИАЛЬНЫМ ПУНКТОМ УФМС РОССИИ 
ПО ПЕНЗЕНСКОЙ ОБЛ ПЕНЗЕНСКОМ РАИОНЕ  10 05 2010  560 040  ЁЭ   ЛЫ  ЁЁ   
ОГ АГАПОВА ОАН ВЕ ЕКАТЕРИНА  МИХАИЛОВНА  ЖЕН 12 05 1996 ГОР ПЕНЗА  ПЕНЗЕНСКОГО  НА  ПЕНЗЕНСКОЙ ОБЛ
```

Answer (score 1):

Сейчас для таких дел нанимают один-два десятка людей на бирже (по типу "распознай капчу"), стОит копейки, а результат и скорость высокие. Кодом же можно облегчить распознавание, но полностью полагаться только на скрипты нельзя.

Для конкретного случая - только многопроходная замена (но, всё равно - нужен постоянный контроль и добавление всё новых условий - универсального ответа или алгоритма нет). Попробуйте скопировать и вставить в верхнее поле текст, который нужно почистить:

```js
let sSTR, rEXP, sStart, sMid, sEnd;

input.addEventListener('input', function() {

  sSTR = this.value;

  rEXP = new RegExp('^(\\D+)([\\s\\d]+)[\\S\\s]+$', 'gim');
  sStart = sSTR.replace(rEXP, '$1$2');

  rEXP = new RegExp('^[\\S\\s]+((ЖЕН|МУЖ)[\\S\\s]+)$', 'gim');
  sEnd = sSTR.replace(rEXP, '$1');

  rEXP = new RegExp(`^${sStart}([\\S\\s]+)${sEnd}$`, 'gim');
  sMid = sSTR.replace(rEXP, '$1').replace(/\d/gim, '');

  output.value = `${sStart}${sMid}${sEnd.replace(/\D(\d)\D/gim, ' ')}`.replace(/\s([\D]{1,2})\s/gim, ' ').replace(/\u0020{2,}/gim, ' ');
  
});
```

```css
body{display:flex;flex-flow:column nowrap;justify-content:space-around;align-items:center;height:100vh;margin:0}textarea{height:40%;width:90%}
```

```html
<textarea id="input"></textarea><textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:
Считаем кол-во цифр в строке. Определяем номера цифр (по счёту), которые нам нужно удалить (т.е. больше 10 и меньше на 8, чем количество цифр). Проходимся циклом по строке и удаляем нужные цифры.

Для подсчёта количества цифр в строке можно с помощью `replace` заменить цифры на `""` и сравнить длины оригинальной строки и получившейся. Узнать является ли символ цифрой можно с помощью регулярок (пост об этом должен быть на stackoverlow, вы без труда найдёте)